# Struggling with paypal notify url

Tags: php, paypal

I have been at this for ages, reading countless tutorials, guides etc from here and paypal with no luck!

I have set up a paypal purchase button on my website. Having tested this with Paypal's sandbox, the payment part works. However on returning to the website it doesn't give the user what they purchased!

This is on the page where they can choose there purchase:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$person?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="5000 Credits for <?=$person?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="5000 Credits">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=$site[location]?>ipn.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$site[location]?>creditsdone.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=$site[location]?>">
    <input src="images/buy_button.gif" height="22" type="image" width="156" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

The creditsdone.php simply says "Thank you for your purchase." This works as you are taken back to this after the purchase is successful.

The ipn.php page however does not work. As on return to the website, no credits are added to the players account.

The following is on the ipn.php page:

```
<?
include("funcs.php"); 


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
// note: additional IPN variables also available -- see IPN documentation
/*$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
*/
if (!$fp) {
  // ERROR
  echo "$errstr ($errno)";
} else {
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        if($_POST[payment_status]=="Completed") {

if ((!fetch("SELECT tranid FROM $tab[paypal] WHERE tranid='$txn_id';")) && ($business == "myemail@email.com"))
   {

$subexpire = time()+864000;

    if($payment_gross == "5.00"){$turns="5000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "10.00"){$turns="7250";}
elseif($payment_gross == "25.00"){$turns="10000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "50.00"){$turns="12500";}
elseif($payment_gross == "100.00"){$turns="25000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "200.00"){$turns="57500";}
elseif($payment_gross == "300.00"){$turns="90000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "400.00"){$turns="132500";}
elseif($payment_gross == "500.00"){$turns="180000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "1000.00"){$turns="400000";}
elseif($payment_gross == "15000.00"){$turns="700000";}

else{$turns="0";}

        $expires=$time+864000;//10 days 
        $total=$payment_gross-$payment_fee;

//update database to add turns to user in game they bought for
        mysql_query("UPDATE $tab[user] SET status='supporter', statusexpire='$expires', credits=credits+$turns WHERE username='$custom'");

//insert into database paypal information
        $buying_user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $custom ."'"));

        $time = time();
        $fetch_the_games = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE starts < $time AND ends > $time");
        while($credit_games = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_the_games))
        {
            mysql_query("UPDATE r$credit_games[round]_pimp SET status = '". supporter ."' WHERE code = '". $buying_user[code] ."'");
        }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tab[paypal] (tranid,amount,fee,user,datebought) VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_gross','$payment_fee','$custom','$time');");
//send email to admin about transaction from paypal--ADMIN-check database to make sure transaction went through to game
        mail_2("$turns credits where bought!","\nDear Admin,\n\nYou just received a payment from $custom for $turns credits\n\nCost: $$payment_gross\nFee: $$payment_fee\n----------\nTotal: $$total","myemail@email.com");

   }else{echo"Cannot refresh transaction!";}

        }
      // check the payment_status is Completed
      // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
      // check that receiver_email is an email address in your PayPal account
      // process payment
      }
      else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
      // log for manual investigation
      }
  }
  fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

I understand this could seem pretty confusing, I'm very new to php and completely stuck so any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: what have you done to debug ipn.php? confirm its hit, confirm the values, confirm the db querry ...

Comment: Check this guide on [testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you should be able to find your issue.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I'll take a look.  Also, sorry Dagon, I'm very new to coding in general. I got the above from a script I bought a while back and have been slowly adding to it whilst I teach myself php. I understand the basics but the above code is a bit over my head! I'm not quite sure what you mean by debug ipn.php?

Comment: there are 50 dozen possibilities you got to learn to debug, echo and check every variable, every query

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here

```
mysql_query("UPDATE r$credit_games
```

Change to

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE credit_games
```

Or to whatever your query name is.

it must be credit_games you have a $ giving error so please take a pause, sleep some hours and then keep working hehehe.

Comment: no because he uses the return value from IPN not the return url

Comment: I think I found the error here mysql_query("UPDATE r$credit_games it must be credit_games you have a $ giving error

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, I'll give it another shot!